# The Limit of $\frac {2^\sqrt { \log(\log n)}}{\log n}$

Tags: limits

Wolfram tells me that the the limit is $0$ when $n$ goes to infinity.
Unfortunately, I have no idea how to prove it...

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac {2^\sqrt { \log(\log n)}}{\log n}.$$

Any help would be appreciated,
thanks in advance.

Comment: Try finding the limit of the logarithm of that expression.

Comment: try l'hopital's rule

Comment: @F'OlaYinka Or not.

Comment: First, realize that you can solve the simpler: $\frac{2^\sqrt{\log m}}{m}$ by setting $m=\log n$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. The *logarithm* of this quantity is $\log 2\cdot\sqrt{\log(\log n)}-\log(\log n)$.
2. When $n\to+\infty$, $\log(\log n)\longrightarrow$ $_________$.
3. When $x\to+\infty$, $\log2\cdot\sqrt{x}-x\longrightarrow$ $_________$.
4. Hence $\log2\cdot\sqrt{\log(\log n)}-\log(\log n)\longrightarrow$ $________$ when $n\to+\infty$.
5. And finally $2^{\sqrt{\log(\log n)}}/\log n\longrightarrow$ $_________$ when $n\to+\infty$.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with $$f(n) = \frac{2^{\sqrt{\log(\log(n))}}}{\log(n)}$$ and taking logarithms $$\log(f(n)) = \log{2}{\sqrt{\log(\log(n))}}  - \log({\log(n)})=\sqrt{\log(\log(n))}\left(\log(2)-\sqrt{\log(\log(n))}\right)$$

then $\sqrt{\log(\log(n))}$ increases towards $+\infty$ with increasing  $n$, while $\left(\log(2)-\sqrt{\log(\log(n))}\right)$ heads towards  $-\infty$, so $\log(f(n))$ heads towards $-\infty$ and $f(n)$ heads towards $0$.